# Completing an entry from a drop down list in one column, based on the choice from another column

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I want to add text to cells in Column C based on what is entered in Column B.  Column B AND Column C are both drop down lists.  So, if in Column B I have chosen Coach Substitution from the drop down list, I need the word 'SUBSTITUTION' to appear in Column C (it is in the drop down list for Column C), if any other choice is made in Column B from that drop down list, Column C remains blank and ready to accept a choice from THAT drop down list.  I keep getting error messages about "You may not use reference operators (such as unions, intersections, and ranges) or array constants for Conditional Formatting criteria.", OR it won't alter anything at all.  YIKES! Help!!??

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you post the formulae you have tried before and clarify what you mean by a drop down list?

Answer (score 0):

The below requires the `C` cell or cells to be populated (won't switch from a validation entry of blank to `SUBSTITUTION`).

Perhaps what you want is to select the relevant ColumnC cells (say C1 or starting at C1) and Format - Conditional formatting..., **Custom formula is** and:

```
=B1="Coach Substitution"
```

with formatting of Custom:

```
"SUBSTITUTION"
```

<kbd>Done</kbd>.